# Using CSS3 to make an arm image wave, almost cracked it but stuck

Tags: css

wondering if someone could help me with making this animation slightly better, it rotates of course at -30degrees but its it possible to rotate it like that but the start of the arm to not rotate as well so it looks more like an arm waving?

```css
.santas-arm {
    animation: wavingArm 2s ease-in-out infinite;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

@keyframes wavingArm {
 0% { 
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px);
 }
 50% { 
  transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(0px);
 }
 100% { 
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="santas-arm"></div>
```

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: You must be missing something because all I got was a black rectangle.

Comment: Yea i just added that in as an example, as the image of the arm is not hosted anywhere but but its more or less that shape.

Comment: Okay, I found why it wasn't animating, you might want to add in `-webkit-` to the beginning of each `keyframe %`.

Comment: Ahh yea, grunt adds all that for me, should of added that in the example sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a matter of setting the `transform-origin`:

```
   transform-origin: left center
```

[**MDN reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin):

> The transform-origin property lets you modify the origin for
>   transformations of an element. For example, the transform-origin of
>   the rotate() function is the centre of rotation. (This property is
>   applied by first translating the element by the negated value of the
>   property, then applying the element's transform, then translating by
>   the property value.)

---

```css
.santas-arm {
  animation: wavingArm 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
@keyframes wavingArm {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="santas-arm"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform-origin` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin))

```css
.santas-arm {
    animation: wavingArm 2s ease-in-out infinite;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

@keyframes wavingArm {
 0% { 
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%
 }
 50% { 
  transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(0px);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%
 }
 100% { 
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="santas-arm"></div>
```